# Как исключить тег из поиска?

Tags: поддержка

Нужна помощь. Как в **поисковике** SO исключить тег, который мне не нужен для поиска? Я знаю, что поиск по тегу это - `[тэг]`, а как исключить ненужный тег, допустим `[android]`?

Comment: `[тэг] -[android]`, см. [Как выполнять поиск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)